# Does 10+ include 10?

Tags: grammar, numbers

If you look on the internet it says 10+ does not include 10 but if you look at Wikipedia it says it does include 10. Which one is correct?

Comment: Isn't Wikipedia _on the internet_?

Comment: Despite having the entire internet to chose from, you have given no context or example sentence/example.

Comment: Edit your question to give context, examples and better focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of examples I can think of where 10+ includes 10, such as the ESRB rating scale used on video games in North America:

[image: all 7 ratings; E 10+ = ages 10 and up]

This image was compiled by [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=16416771011) and uses the exact wording from the [ESRB website](https://www.esrb.org/ratings-guide/). There are three ratings that include a plus: "Everyone 10+", "Mature 17+", and "Adults Only 18+". The full description makes it clear that each of these includes the number ("ages 10 and up"). Furthermore these icons appear without this explanatory text on the video game boxes themselves, so it is expected that the consumer intuitively understands that "10+" means "greater than or equal to 10 years old".

For another example, the tabletop game [Dungeon World](https://www.dungeonworldsrd.com/playing-the-game/) uses "10+" to mean a roll totaling 10 or higher. It has to, because the other ranges are "7-9" and "6-".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is awkward. [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plus) gives the definition excluding the (lower) endpoint:

> **plus** [adjective]
>
> ...
>
> [after noun] ... more than the number or amount mentioned:
>
> - *temperatures of 40 plus*
> - *Those cars cost £20,000 plus.*

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plus) and [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/plus) concur.

BUT [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/plus) gives the definition including the endpoint:

> **plus** [adjective]
>
> 1 [postpositive] [after a number or amount] at least.
>
> - *companies put losses at $500,000 plus ...*
> - *Job losses too had a look of inevitability about then, but the two hundred and thirty plus was well above general expectations*.

And [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/plus_1) is in agreement here.

[Don't confuse the conflicting usage (again from Lexico)

> 1.1 (after a grade) rather better than
>
> - *B plus*]

With large numbers, the difference becomes trivial (we'd round $500 000·01 to $500 000 anyway). But '10+ jurors must agree' say is a very different case, requiring a precise interpretation.

I'd normally take the end-point-included definition licensed by Lexico (perhaps swayed by the fact that the famous 11-plus exam [[Farlex](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/11-plus)] in the UK was for 11- and 12-year-old children). However, in crucial cases, one needs to enquire about the local controlling stipulative definition.